# Install php70-mcrypt on mac high sierra

Tags: macos, php-7, mcrypt

I've installed mcrypt using Homebrew but it doesn't seem to be loading. I installed by running:

```
brew install php70-mcrypt
```

When I run phpinfo() in a browser I don't see mcrypt installation details (apart from the module authors).

****Is nginx using the same php that I get from the command line? Or am I not installing / enabling mcrypt properly?****

#### Using phpinfo() in the browser:

phpinfo tells me the .ini path:

[image: phpinfo() screenshot extract]

If I check the /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d directory, there are two .ini files:

1. ext-intl.ini
2. ext-mcrypt.ini

but they don't appear to have been parsed. The mcrypt one (the one I'm trying to get working) contains:

[image: screenshot of ext-mcrypt.ini contents]

and /usr/local/opt/php70-mcrypt is a symlink to the Cellar location /usr/local/Cellar/php70-mcrypt/7.0.27_19, which contains the mcrypt.so file.

I've tried adding the extension to the php.ini file directly, both with and without the path. Each time I save the file then restart php (not sure if necessary...) and nginx:

```
brew services restart php70
brew services restart nginx
```

Still not loading.

#### Using the terminal:

If I run this from the terminal:

```
php -i | grep mcrypt
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, 
string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, 
dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

There appears to be more detail here.

****Is nginx using a different php from the command line? How can I make sure nginx is using the php I see at the command line if this is the problem? Or alternatively, how can I install php to the "other" php that nginx uses?****

The underlying reason for this is to load Magento 2, which is giving me this error which I think confirms that mcrypt really isn't loading properly:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' in /[MY DOC ROOT]/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 397
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph I'm only using mcrypt because it is a Magento (latest version 2.2) dependancy: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Then I guess is the problem is Magento, they should not be using deprecated and removed packages, especially security related.

Answer (score 0):

I got mcrypt installed. As I suspected, nginx was using a different php version (7.0.26) because the new version (7.0.27) wasn't able to listen to port 9000 since it was already in use. For reference, I found this by checking the php-fpm.log file.

To fix this, I used the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/567203/php-fastcgi-wont-stop-trying-to-start-php-fpm) to find and kill the processes.

I found the processes running:

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Then killed them (there were four):

```
kill [PID]
```

Then started php:

```
brew services php70 start
```

Now my phpinfo page shows that 7.0.27 is running and mcrypt was installed:

[image]

Its worth noting the comment from @zaph - mcrypt is deprecated. I'm only getting it running so that I can use Magento as it is a dependency.